# Need help understanding a fairly vague solution to example problem (the topic is noise in CMOS circuits)

Tags: transistors, mosfet, noise, cmos, low-noise-amplifier

So I have the solution to the following example problem I am working on:

[image]

Now the issue is that I am trying to understand the solution I was given:

[image]
The thing is this solution is simply quite vague. Could someone possibly help me understand how the three terms present in the final answer were derived?

Comment: The solution is not vague, all the terms in the solution are well known and well defined. Are you saying you don't understand what some of the terms in the solution represent? If so, tell us which parts of the solution you *do* understand, and then you may get help with the rest.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I understand pretty well how to get Rout.  I've derived it once using small signal analysis and since then I've simply remembered it.  Now here's where I am stuck.  I understand that there are three parts of the circuit that I need to draw either voltage or current sources that represent noise.   What I have tried so far is drawing a current source in parallel with M2, voltage source inputted into the gate of M1, and a current source in parallel with resistor Rs.  However, this set up either gets me nowhere or I can't see where to go from that set up.